# Show/Hide Content without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have three content boxes that i want to show and hide using controls.
The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="leermat1"> 
  Content here 
  <a class="pag-next">Next</a>
 <a class="pag-prev">Previous</a>
</div>
<div id="leermat2"> 
  Content here 
  <a class="pag-next">Next</a>
 <a class="pag-prev">Previous</a>
</div>
<div id="leermat3"> 
  Content here 
  <a class="pag-next">Next</a>
 <a class="pag-prev">Previous</a>
</div>
```

I have the two anchors pag-next and pag-prev that will control which of  the content divs should be visible at any given point:

I want to write jquery such as, when #leermat1 'pag-next' is clicked, it hides #leermat1 and shows #leermat2. Then when #leermat1 is hidden and #leermat2 shows, when '.pag-next' is clicked, it hides #leermat2, and shows #leermat3.

Also the 'pag-prev' should work the same way.

I started with the following but dont know where to go from here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pag-next').on('click',function() {
        $('#leermat1').addClass('hide');
        $('#leermat2').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

One more thing is that the '.pag-next' should stop functioning after it has shown #leermat3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me through a little trial and error. Although I am not sure if this is the most efficient solution.

```
         $('#leermat1 .pag-next').on('click',function(){
            $('#leermat1').addClass('hide');
            $('#leermat1').removeClass('show');
            $('#leermat3').addClass('hide');
            $('#leermat3').remove('show');
            $('#leermat2').addClass('show');    
        });
        $('#leermat2 .pag-next').on('click',function(){
            $('#leermat1').removeClass('show');
            $('#leermat2').addClass('hide');
            $('#leermat2').removeClass('show');
            $('#leermat3').addClass('show');
        });

        $('#leermat2 .pag-prev').on('click',function(){
            $('#leermat2').addClass('hide');
            $('#leermat2').removeClass('show');
            $('#leermat1').addClass('show');
            $('#leermat3').removeClass('show');
        });
        $('#leermat3 .pag-prev').on('click',function(){
            $('#leermat3').addClass('hide');
            $('#leermat2').addClass('show');
            $('#leermat1').addClass('hide');
            $('#leermat3').removeClass('show');
            $('#leermat1').removeClass('show');
        });
```

Comment: Would highly appreciate any comments/suggestions in improving this. This would help and visitors who need a same solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need this

```
$('[class^=pag-]').click(function() {
    var elem = $('[id^=leermat]').filter(":visible"); // take the visible element
    var num = Number(elem[0].id.match(/\d+$/)[0]); // take the number from it
    var step = $(this).is('.pag-next') ? 1 : -1; // ternary operator
    $('#leermat'+ (num + step)).show(); // show next or back
    elem.hide(); // hide the visible element
});
```

Comment: this is really good.. thanks Amit. Only issue is that now when it shows the third 'leermat' id which is the last content div, if the user clicks on 'pag-next' again it hides the third content div and since there is nothing to replace it with the page goes blank. Is there a way to make the 'pag-next not work after it has showed 'leermat3'. so that from there it can only go back 'page-prev'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your anchor tag you have not given it a class.

```
<a href="pag-next">Next</a>
```

You then go on in your JQuery code to add a click function to a class which does not exist.

```
 $('.pag-next').on('click',function()
```

Try adding `class="pag-next"` to your anchor  tag.